# How can I get jQTouch mobile views working with Devise for "sign in" and "register"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, jqtouch

I have a Rails 3 app and I'm using Devise and jQTouch.

I've got all of my mobile views working except for "sign in" and "register".

When I try to sign in using the mobile version, I get the following:

```
Missing template user_sessions/create with {:locale=>[:en, :en], :formats=>[:mobile],     :handlers=>[:rxml, :erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml]} in view paths
```

For other controllers, I added format.mobile and created mobile views, but for sign in and register I am having trouble sorting them out.

Any ideas on how to get my jQTouch mobile views working with Devise for sign in and register?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do 2 things.

1) in config/initializers/devise.rb you need to add :mobile as an accepted type.
To do this find the line that says:

```
config.navigational_formats = [:html]
```

And add :mobile to it so it should now read:

```
config.navigational_formats = [:html, :mobile]
```

2) You need to create another initializer file and add the following code to it:

```
ActionController::Responder.class_eval do
  alias :to_mobile :to_html
end
```

This will make it so that all devise redirects work.

If you need more information check out the devise wiki

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki